# basic rspec test not passing

Tags: ruby, rspec

Would appreciate if someone could tell me why this won't pass, it's getting nil instead of value

```
class Hello
  def hi
    puts "hello"
  end
end


describe Hello do

  before do
    @obj = Hello.new
  end

  describe "#hi" do
    it "should say hello" do
      @obj.hi.should == "hello"
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `puts` always returns `nil`, `#hi` always returns `nil`.

Change it to:

```
class Hello
  def hi
    "hello"
  end
end
```

Comment: It's part of the learning process. Do RSpec for 10 hours a day for 3 months and it will be much easier.

Answer (score 2):

`puts` just outputs the string, but returns `nil` as the value, so `hi` is just returning that nil value.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but you should also be able to test against $stdout. It should receive the